# How to prevent expanded React-Table row from collapsing on re-render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, react-table

I have a simple [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/examples.md) with an expanded sub component whose data is tied to a Redux state object.

When the sub component gets expanded, I trigger an api call to get some additional data to be lazy-loaded onto the redux store. The redux store gets updated with the new data and the sub component DOM gets successfully updated as well, but **the problem is the expanded row doesn't stay expanded after the re-render. It collapses.**

Is there a way to keep my expanded rows expanded even after the redux store gets updated and a re-render is triggered?

Comment: Is the state of the collapsed component also handled by Redux? Something like: `isChildExpanded: boolean`

Comment: @r3dst0rm No. The redux store just has the data object for my table and subcomponents. But I think I see where you're going with this ☺

Comment: @LCIII - provide an example of the problem, probably just need to keep expanded state, but it may be more complex like accidental unmounting. For what it's worth, I would put expanded state in redux (personal opinion), it sounds like it's local state unless you need to retain it across mounts/unmounts.

Comment: Yep, I'm with @Adam here. Put the expanded state into Redux (that's where I'd put it too), to contain it over multiple (re-)renderings. [Some additional thoughts if you dislike the Redux idea: Maybe there would also be an option to write a custom hook to achieve the same, but that sounds nasty. A custom context could also well be used to solve this issue.]

Comment: Whoops. I actually meant to say I would **NOT** put expanded state in redux, unless you need to.

Comment: Yes, you should not keep simple flags for UI in redux, for this problem you should probably keep it in table's parent state

Answer (score 7):

Set `autoResetExpanded` to false in configuration, more details - https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useExpanded

Answer (score 1):

For me, setting `collapseOnDataChange` to false worked

You could also try `freezeWhenExpanded` property and set it to true.